# cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'

Tags: c++, gcc, stream, operator-keyword

I define in a class A an << operator like this :
A.h :

```
class API_name A {
    friend API_name std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const A&a);
}
```

A.cpp :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const A& a);
```

In another file including A.h, I want to do this :

```
void fonction(const A* a) {
    std::cout << "a contains : " << *a << std::endl;
}
```

At this line, I gcc returns the following error :

error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'

Can someone tell me why and how to avoid this compilation error?

Answer (score 1):

You `friend` definition mistakenly omitted a `&`:

That is,

```
class API_name A {
    friend API_name std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream o, const A&a);
}
```

should be

```
class API_name A {
    friend API_name std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const A&a);
}
```

Comment: The & is mentionned in definition. I have made a typing error while I was writing the question and I get this compilation error.

Comment: @FlashMcQueen: Then the problem is not in the code you posted, at least as far as we can see. You may need to post a [mcve]. For example, what are `API_name` and how are your classes and functions arranged within namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition and implementation do not match.

- A.h: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream o, const A&a);`
- A.cpp: `stream& DTL::operator<<(ostream& o, const A& a);`

Your A.h file needs to change to: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const A&a);`